# Who are Li Luo and Ka Suo's past reincarnations?

Tags: ice-fantasy

In one of Li Luo's past reincarnations (before Luo Luo), she's speaking with one of Ka Suo's reincarnations and says that he was able to escape death by writing "a poem in seven steps." This is clearly a reference to "[The Quatrain of Seven Steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quatrain_of_Seven_Steps)," suggesting that Feng Suo's preincarnation is Cao Zhi.

It thus seems probable that Ka Suo and Li Luo's other reincarnations, shown on-screen were famous figures, not just random period-appropriate people. Who were they (and who was Li Luo's incarnation in the scene with Cao Zhi)?